# JFrame waiting for data reception to perform its task

Tags: java, swing, jframe, observer-pattern

I have two different and independent `JFrame` windows:

1. `DataFrame`
2. `GraphFrame`

The first one is for the user to manipulate, with the input of different values and patterns to display on a graph presented in 2). The 1) sends specific values to 2) (array with doubles) so that "GraphFrame" can create the graph.

I invoke the "main " method from GraphFrame in the "main" method of DataFrame so that they both run at the same time and are both visible during the whole process.

I want these frames to be completely independent, which means that the mission for 1) is to send values and the mission for 2) is to check when values are recieved and then create the graph.

I also prefer to keep most of the methods private, so that they can't be accessed from external sources.

My problem, is that I don't know which is the best way to implement this data exchange. What is the best way for Frame 2) keep "listening" for the values it needs to recieve?

Should I create getters/setters on 2) and with the help of an Observer https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer ?

Or should I use threads?

Or even the creation of a  traditional loop that keeps waiting for values, like:

```
while(array.isEmpty()) {
     //stuck here
}
//create the graph from the values in array
```

At the moment I am receiving the values in 2) from setter methods, but I am uncapable, so far, of performing the code I desire only after I get the values.

What do you think is the best way to implement this?

P.S.: Should I consider not invoking `GraphFrame` main from `DataFrame` and run these 2 separately?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *"JFrame waiting for data reception to perform its task"* Convert one frame to a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`. Query the controls immediately after `setVisible(true)`. The code statements following that call will only proceed once it is closed.

Comment: Hello @AndrewThompson, I've already seen and read that thread multiple times before, and I've been using layouts to avoid multiple JFrames. However, for what I am creating, I need these 2 (and will only be 2), because the "DataFrame" one is simulating a real environment, so, it is mostly used to test "GraphFrame". It is indeed to create the impression that are 2 different apps and not just one. Hence my P.S. in my thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you're trying to run both JFrames in the same application. Conceptually this is rather **one** UI split into two windows than *running* two Frames as you put it.

Swing requires all UI elements to be updated by **one** thread - the AWT-Thread. Also interaction with the UI will run in the AWT-Thread. You need to take this into account.

Also it is best practice to separate data model and view. To solve your problem you could create a model for the GraphFrame that is manipulated by changes on the DataFrame. These changes could e.g. be picked up by a listener on the model that uses SwingUtils.invokeLater() to update the GraphFrame.

Of course there is a number of Issues you might need to care for additionally and depending on your requirements you might need to further decouple the two parts.

Comment: Oh ok. Then to accomplish the mission of being independent from each other (these frames), should I create them as two different applications? This way they would be completely separate. This way how could I make the connection between the two?

On the other hand, you suggested the invokeLater() method, but I didn't understand how it really works (sorry, never used it before).

Answer (score 0):

You could try having the GraphFrame initialize and then stop, but have a (static/nonstatic) method in GraphFrame that DataFrame can call to update the graph. Afterwards, repaint GraphFrame.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: That is indeed a possibility! However, I will need to have an option that the graph in GraphFrame must be updated in real time or updated every 2 or 3 seconds to continue drawing it (not drawing the whole thing entirely).
And with this, I would need to be updating the graph every 2/3 seconds, but I only want to "press a button " (make an action) on DataFrame, and then GraphFrame can handle all this by itself.